# Are there any distinctions between "du jour" and "currency"?

Tags: meaning, difference, vocabulary

Source: Dictionary.com

du jour

1)as prepared on the particular day; of the kind being served today:
The soup du jour is split pea.

2)fashionable; current:
environmentalism and other issues du jour.

currency

1. something that is used as a medium of exchange; money.

2)general acceptance; prevalence; vogue.

3)a time or period during which something is widely accepted and circulated.

4)the fact or quality of being widely accepted and circulated from person to person.

5)circulation, as of coin.

In spite of these words having different parts of speech, I sense a shared sense between these two words (I am referring to the 2nd definition of du jour and the 2nd&3rd definitions of currency). How is that these two words (2nd definition of du jour and the 2nd&3rd definitions of currency) are similar? I'm stumped. Let me know in the comment section below.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between a noun and an adjective?

Comment: I'm CV'ing because the question is vague. OP asks how the terms are similar but already has the answer (i.e., their meanings are similar). What else is he or she looking for?

Answer (score 2):

[As you point out, these two words are **different parts of speech**, and so **cannot be used interchangeably**]

Yes, **there is a similarity** between the specific senses you point out. However, bbefore anything else, you should know some information about the words we are discussing:

1. Senses two and three of currency, as you list them, are *very old-fashioned*. They are so old-fashioned that I would wager an average speaker would be surprised by the use.
2. Du jour often implies that the thing that is fashionable is a *fad*, or the thing that is current is *not going to be current for very long*. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/du_jour#English) defines Du jour as

> Currently stylish; en vogue; trendy; **favoured now but likely temporary**; latest.

Nevertheless, as you point out, *du jour* is sometimes used to describe something fashionable or *current*, and *currency* sometimes refers to fashionableness or degree of acceptance. One might say that

> Chaucer's writings, which once had so much **currency**, are now out of fashion. One day, perhaps they will again be the texts **du jour**.

As to *why* this is the case, it's not clear how to answer this. Many words that are from completely different sources have similar meanings. Consider, for instance *belly* (a word of Germanic origin) and *abdomen* (from Latin).

In this case, *du jour* is a french phrase meaning "of the day," which is a clear synonym of *current*. *Currency* is equivalent to **current-ness*--the quality of being current; of the day. So you can see how they've ended up with the same meaning in some senses.

Comment: Mainly, in my experience, _du jour_ seems to be more seen in US English sources.

Comment: Senses 2 and 3 of "currency" are absolutely NOT old-fashioned; they are used quite widely, in fact. Here is just one recent example (subtitle): https://www.heyuguys.com/donnie-yen-joins-keanu-reeves-in-john-wick-4/

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I can only speak to my own experiences. Though I am fairly well-read and talk with people from many backgrounds, to my ear those two senses are uncommon. As to the article you quote, it seems either poorly edited or written by a non-native English speaker. There are many unusual phrases: "Donnie Yen has been signed up by Chad Stahelski," "Yen is said to be playing [...] an old friend of Reeve's John Wick, who shares his same history," (who share's whose "same" history?) "Erica Lee and Stahelski will produce." Other articles by the same author have similar unusual phrases.

Comment: It's hard to find good examples because 1) meaning 1 dwarfs meanings 2 and 3 and 2) meanings 2 and 4 are very similar. However, a little Googling turned up: [*The struggles of the white, heterosexual, elite, western woman have gained currency as the only history of feminism setting itself up as a role model for the rest of the world.*](https://blogs.lse.ac.uk/medialse/2021/09/02/afghanistan-and-the-colonial-project-of-feminism-dismantling-the-binary-lens/)

Comment: And: [*Instead, we need to apply the principles of "harm reduction," which is a public health philosophy that recognizes this reality and has gained currency in recent years.*](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/what-fighting-covid-and-fighting-drug-addiction-have-in-common/) There are many other examples from reputable sources.